# Add the Attention mechanism for producing heatmaps output from the neural network

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, attention-model

I have this neural network that takes in input the rgb image and 2 other variations of it (fixed and dynamic). I would like to add the mechanism of "attention" to have in output the heatmap of the test instances.

```
def build_model():
  inputRGB = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128,128,3), name='train_ds')
  inputFixed = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128,128,3), name='fixed_ds')
  inputDinamic = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128,128,3), name='dinamic_ds')

    #  RGB images
  rgb = models.Sequential()  
  rgb = layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding='SAME')(inputRGB)
  rgb = layers.PReLU()(rgb)
  rgb = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(rgb)
  rgb = layers.BatchNormalization()(rgb)
  rgb = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(rgb)
  rgb = layers.PReLU()(rgb)
  rgb = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(rgb)
  rgb = layers.PReLU()(rgb)
  rgb = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(rgb)
  rgb = layers.PReLU()(rgb)
  rgb = layers.Dropout(0.5)(rgb)
  rgb = layers.GlobalAvgPool2D()(rgb)
  rgb = Model(inputs = inputRGB, outputs=rgb)

    # First type of density 
  fixed = models.Sequential()
  fixed = layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding='SAME')(inputFixed)
  fixed = layers.PReLU()(fixed)
  fixed = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(fixed)
  fixed = layers.BatchNormalization()(fixed)
  fixed = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(fixed)
  fixed = layers.PReLU()(fixed)
  fixed = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(fixed)
  fixed = layers.PReLU()(fixed)
  fixed = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(fixed)
  fixed = layers.PReLU()(fixed)
  fixed = layers.Dropout(0.5)(fixed)
  fixed = layers.GlobalAvgPool2D()(fixed)
  fixed = Model(inputs = inputFixed, outputs=fixed)

    # Second type of density
  dinamic = models.Sequential()  
  dinamic = layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding='SAME')(inputDinamic)
  dinamic = layers.PReLU()(dinamic)
  dinamic = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(dinamic)
  dinamic = layers.BatchNormalization()(dinamic)
  dinamic = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(dinamic)
  dinamic = layers.PReLU()(dinamic)
  dinamic = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(dinamic)
  dinamic = layers.PReLU()(dinamic)
  dinamic = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(dinamic)
  dinamic = layers.PReLU()(dinamic)
  dinamic = layers.Dropout(0.5)(dinamic)
  dinamic = layers.GlobalAvgPool2D()(dinamic)
  dinamic = Model(inputs = inputDinamic, outputs=dinamic)

  concat = layers.concatenate([rgb.output, fixed.output, dinamic.output])  # merge the outputs of the two models
  k = layers.Dense(1)(concat)

  modelFinal = Model(inputs={'train_ds':inputRGB, 'fixed_ds':inputFixed, 'dinamic_ds':inputDinamic}, outputs=[k])

  opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, amsgrad=False)


  modelFinal.compile(optimizer=opt , loss='mae', metrics=['mae'])
  return modelFinal
```

Unfortunately, this is the first time I've used such mechanization. From what I could study I should insert an attention layer between the concatenate and the Dense layer. But, is this the correct way to produce heatmaps as output?

Comment: After which layer do you want a heatmap? Creation of heatmaps that actually mean something can only be done beforee GAP, and preferably in the middle or early Conv layers.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal I imagined it had to be done before GAP. To explain: I would like to generate a heatmap from the RGB sub-network. I am not interested in having a heatmap output from the other two sub-networks (fixed and dynamic)

Comment: You need to fix the layer in a network from which you want to get a heatmap, not a whole network. As a general rule, attention maps from deeper layers don't give much information visually.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal and how can I do that? Assuming I want to put it right before GAP, after Dropout. I saw the attention layer in tf.keras (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Attention) but I didn't understand how to use it to get the heatmap.

Answer (score 1):

The Attention layer present in Tensorflow is aimed towards sequential data.

Convolutional networks for images use two several different kinds of attention mechanisms:

1. Self attention mechanism (Check this great [medium](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/understanding-deep-self-attention-mechanism-in-convolution-neural-networks-e8f9c01cb251) article)
2. Direct weightmap prediction, by adding a 1 x 1 convolution with 1 filter after the layer you want to attened to, having sigmoid activation.
3. Using Gaussian 2D attention, where x and y coordinates are specified, on a specific kernel.

However, all these methods are parameterized and require training. Your use case is different.

To obtain a heatmap from a layer, I usually extract the kernel with the highest mean activation values. This alone is often not enough, so I use the top k kernels with highest mean activation values.

To obtain a kernel with the highest activation values, the pseudocode is:

> Run the model on an input, with batch size 1
>
> Extract the output of the layer you want the heatmaps of. This will be of the shape (1, h, w, filters). Assign this to a variable (say "outputs")
>
> Perform GAP on "outputs" and squeeze to get a vector of shape (filters,). The argmax of this vector will give the kernel having the highest mean activation. Let's call the output of argmax "kernel_number"
>
> Plot "outputs"[0, :, :, "kernel_number"]. This is the heatmap you are looking for.

Comment: i'm going to try, but i have another questions:
if i want to replicate this (https://github.com/gvessio/uav-crowd-detection/blob/master/crowd_detector.ipynb) but not using a grad-cam but a post-hoc attention (described here https://towardsdatascience.com/learn-to-pay-attention-trainable-visual-attention-in-cnns-87e2869f89f1), on this sub-network (https://pastebin.com/zb9Gkdng) extracted from a trained model derived from the previous described multi-input neural network, it is possible?

Comment: Is it possible: Yes. How to do it: you'll have to experiment.

Comment: Okay, so can I still broadly consider the pseudocode you described above?